# ¿Cómo puedo encoger un header con React al hacer un scroll vertical?

Tags: jquery, css, meteor, reactjs

Encontré un ejemplo para encoger un header utilizando css y javascript en ésta página [codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED) traté de realizarlo con React pero no puedo implementarlo de la misma manera al parecer mi función jquery está funcionando mal, ¿Cuál creen que sea la solución?

Ésta es mi plantilla del header llamada `NavbarFixed.js`

```
import React from 'react';

class NavbarFixed extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var miniCabecera = 300;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
            if (scroll >= miniCabecera) {
                $('#header-fixed').addClass('shrink');
            } else {
                $('#header-fixed').removeClass('shrink');
            }
        });
        function getCurrentScroll() {
            return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <div className="header-fixed">
                <h1>Animated Fixed  Header (Scroll Down)</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="content"></div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
export default NavbarFixed;
```

y éstos son los estilos

```
.header-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cc5350;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:160px;

}
.header-fixed.shrink {
    height: 100px;
    line-height:80px;
}
.header-fixed h1
{
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header-fixed.shrink h1
{
    font-size:24px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.content
{
height:2000px;
 /*just to get the page to scroll*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar haces `className="header-fixed"`, y sin embargo con jquery pones
`if (scroll >= miniCabecera) {
                $('#header-fixed').addClass('shrink');
            } else {
                $('#header-fixed').removeClass('shrink');
            }`
que intenta buscar el elemento por id

Tendrías en jquery que poner $('.header-fixed')
O bien en el código react declarar el elemento como id='header-fixed'

No sé si hay más problemas, pero esto está mal